# Does Chrome OS support Node Js apps?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-os, nwjs

I have a [nwjs](https://nwjs.io/) app for Windows and Mac. I want to use the same code for creating an app for Chrome OS. This app contains **NodeJS** code, I am trying to figure out if NodeJS is supported by ChromeOS. I tried to install the folder as unpacked extension in the Chrome but looks like it is not able to figure out the `require` function and other Node related functions. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you can't use NodeJS in a Chrome Extension. However, it is now (since around May 2018) possible to easily enable a Linux container in ChromeOS, in which you can install NodeJS and run corresponding apps.

For example, I have an [electron](https://electronjs.org/) app, and I was able to generate a Linux package for it using [`electron-forge`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/) and run it on ChromeOS using the Linux container. Performance was not great though, and some features, such as use of serial ports with [`node-serialport`](https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport), were not yet available.

See also [*Linux apps on Chrome OS: An easy-to-follow guide*](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3314739/chrome-os/how-to-use-linux-apps-on-chrome-os.html)